# How can I run this command in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, x264, mplayer

This is my shell script but it gives errors:

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts "i:o:" flag
do
   case $flag in
   i) file_input=$OPTARG
   ;;
   o) file_output=$OPTARG
   ;;
   esac
done

mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(x264 --demuxer y4m \
              --crf 20 --threads auto --output $file_output - ) $file_input
```

The error message is:

> Can't get memory or file handle to write ">(x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 20 --threads auto --output video.264 - )"!FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.

When I run this cmd on putty:

```
mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(x264 --demuxer y4m \
              --crf 20 --threads auto --output video.264 - ) video.wmv
```

it works perfectly..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All solutions are not functionality..

Answer (score 4):

The command you're using uses an intricate bash's [pipe stream to subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) syntax, i.e. `>()` to achieve what you want. Probably your `/bin/sh` (that you invoke as a shell for this script in shebang) is not the same as the shell you're using interactively (i.e. bash)?

Comment: /bin/sh is probably a link to /bin/bash, but under the name /bin/sh, not all the features of bash are available - and the '`=>`' notation in particular is not supported.

Comment: @Jonathan: there is no `=>` notation. The `=` is part of the mplayer command. `>(...)` is what Bash parses.

Comment: Not always. Nowadays Ubuntu & Debian are popular, and `/bin/sh` is usually implemented with dash there, which is a very minimalistic strictly POSIX-compatible shell.

Comment: @thkala: You're probably correct - the problems start between the = and the >, and /bin/sh doesn't like it and /bin/bash does.  So it is 'process substitution' again...makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The [`>(...)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) process substitution operator is Bash-specific. It is also not available if Bash is called as `/bin/sh`, because in that case Bash restricts itself to a more compliant subset of its features.

Just use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` at the start of your script.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add some `'` to protect you special chars:

```
mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo 'yuv4mpeg:file=>(x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 20 --threads auto --output $file_output - )' $file_input
```